# Use local folder as package.json repository

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, package.json

Is there a way to setup a local folder to be used as package.json repository. The goal is to be able to use the cloud repository (https://www.npmjs.com/package) but the modules which are not found there to be searched and installed from a local folder.

Example package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "standard-npm-module": "1.0.0", // installed from https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-npm-module
    "local-module": "1.0.0", // installed from local folder because it wont be found in https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-module
  }
}
```

PS Yarn or npm any solution will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths). for instance, see the `package.json` snippet below.

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
  }
}
```

you can also leverage npm, for instance:

```sh
npm install --save /path/to/module
```